# does the JDBC end user need the actual database installed?

Tags: java, jdbc

let's say I have a java app to connect to a, for example, MySQL database (or any other similar database). Now I want to give this app to the end user. Do they have to install MySQL on their computer? The user doesn't have access to the Internet, by the way.

Comment: No,  The MySQL database can be available on a publicly accessible website that the app connects to.

Comment: Web access is not going to do anyone any good if the application isn't coded to take advantage of it. The fact is that OP hasn't provided enough details about his app.

Comment: What if they don't have access to an Internet connection?

Comment: Why don't you just edit your question and explain how your application is set up? Your question isn't answerable in its current state.

Comment: I'm really confused. What, exactly, is vague about my question? that's the simplest way to put a question.

Comment: No less than Albert Einstein said "make things as simple as possible, but not simpler." You've made it so simple that you left out basic information that has already been pointed out in previous comments. Did you write an application with network communication ability or not? Can you not see how the answer depends wholly on the design of the application? There is no general case to be stated here.

Comment: I edited the question...

Comment: If you want the user to connect to a database, you need to be able to access the database. If the database is online, then the user needs online access. If you intend the database to be locally reachable offline, you must make sure the user has the database locally installed. Did I catch you correctly?

Comment: Dear  Pål Brattberg, yes! That answers my question clearly. If you change your comment into an answer I'd tag it as "accepted" ... Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether you have access to the location where the DB is .

If your DB is hosted on a public network & you have access to it over the internet , then the user need not  install a local instance of the database [ MySQL in your example] on their computer.

But if the user has no access to the internet , then you will have to install a local copy of the DB for the JDBC driver to talk to it.

Comment: This clearly answers my question. Thank you ...